Discord.js Slash Commands Crash
As I was following the guide on https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html#individual-command-files I stumble a problem named ENOENT -4058 when trying to read the commands location and turn into an array using fs.readdirSync(). My files are placed like in the GitHub repository the page has a reference. The only difference is that I used .env with this code instead of using a config.js file. In addition I installed nodemon to save and run the code constantly. What can I do to solve this? Here is my code
require('dotenv').config();

const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');

// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');


// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ]
});

client.commands = new Collection();
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);


for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

client.once(Events.ClientReady, readyClient => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${readyClient.user.tag}`);
});

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
});


client.login(process.env.TOKEN);

Exact error message on img
enter image description here
To solve it I tried using console.log(commandFolders) after const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath); to print the array but it wasn't printing to screen... So my theory is that somehow this isn't getting the inside the utility subfolder to get the js file names in the array. But I have no idea of what I can modify to make it work

The error you're getting comes from the following
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

You tell your program to look for the commands folder inside of your src folder. But looking at the screenshot you have provided the commands folder is not located in the src folder. You can either move the commands folder inside of the src folder or you have to edit your code.
If you change it a bit it should look for the commands folder at the correct path:
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, '../commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

Hope this helps.
